# How do I create a page list in wordpress that includes data-hover="PAGETITLEHERE"?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok have a question did some research and got it to work so I can put spans in my li's which work great but in the span I have a data-hover tag and inside it I want to put the title of the page but cant figure out how.

As well it shows all the pages when I just want to show the childs of the parent which I have done before but when changing the echo $pages to echo$children it works and shows all the children but then removes my span info.

Can anyone help heres the code...

```
{ if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
        else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        if ($children) { ?>
            <ul class="cl-effect-2" id="cl-effect-2">
                <?php
        $pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&title_li=');
        $pages = str_replace('">', '"><span data-hover="PAGETITLEHERE">', $pages);
        $pages = str_replace('<span data-hover="PAGETITLEHERE"><a', '<a', $pages);
        $pages = str_replace('</a>', '</span></a>', $pages);
        echo $pages;
    ?>
            </ul>
     <?php } ?> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You replaces the `$pages` variable with `str_replace`, try to use the `$children` variable instead.

```
{ if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
        <ul class="cl-effect-2" id="cl-effect-2">
            <?php
    $pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&title_li=');
    $children = str_replace('">', '"><span data-hover="PAGETITLEHERE">', $pages);
    $children = str_replace('<span data-hover="PAGETITLEHERE"><a', '<a', $pages);
    $children = str_replace('</a>', '</span></a>', $pages);
    echo $children;
?>
        </ul>
 <?php } ?> }
```

Comment: Neme, What to put instead PAGETITLEHERE  
for appear title of the page

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer

in funktion.php i put hook

```
    add_filter( 'wp_list_pages', 'wp_list_pages_hook', 11, 2 );
function wp_list_pages_hook( $output, $r ){
    if( ! is_front_page() ){
        $output = preg_replace('~<a([^>]+)>(.*?)</a>~', '<a $1 > <span data-hover="$2">$2</span></a>', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

In header.php now I can use a simple

```
<?php wp_list_pages('exclude=41&title_li='); ?>
```